# Wide-lens hyperlapse (timelapse) camera on Samsung S10

Tags: gratis, android, camera

I love Samsung S10's wide-angle lens, but unfortunately the Samsung camera app does not allow it to be used in "hyperlapse" mode (=timelapse mode).

Is there an app that allows Samsung S10 smartphones to record timelapses using the camera's physical wide-angle camera?

Requirements:

- Uses the full resolution of Samsung S10's wide-angle camera.
- Gratis, ideally open source.
- No watermarks.

Ideally:

- Allows to select speed (examples: 1 second per minute, 1 second per hour, etc)
- Allows to select aspect ratio

Non-solutions:

- Microsoft Hyperlapse is not good because it records in low resolution. Also, it stitches unfashionable Microsoft auto-promotion frames at the end of your videos.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really intuitive, but the [Time Spirit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mountaindehead.timelapsproject) camera app can be used for that.

The trick to switch to the wide-angle camera: In the three dots menu, there is a button to switch to selfie mode. Push it twice, and you will be in wide-angle mode. The full cycle is:

Normal camera -> selfie camera -> wide-angle camera -> selfie camera -> normal camera -> etc

Gratis.

Flaws of this app:

- Does not use the full sensor. It outputs 2364x1836 videos, which is ridiculously elongated for a wide-angle video. The S10 is capable of taking 3648x2736 pictures, so a time lapse app should be able to achieve that.
- Does not record more than 4 gigabytes. This [used to be an Android limitation](https://pocketnow.com/android-11-finally-lifts-the-4gb-file-size-limit-for-recording-videos-sort-of) but even then it should continue recording in new files (I have 14 gigabytes of free space). Instead, after reaching 4 gigabytes it pretends that it is still recording but actually does not record anymore. Workaround: Stop and start a new recording every ~4 hours, then stitch the videos using avidemux or similar.
- The main screen of the app says "To view this section, you need to login". DO NOT log in, as it creepily tries to access your contacts, instead ignore the log in button and press the round `+` button which allows you to create a video lapse.